# New monitor not detecting an signal from my laptop (running Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: external-monitor

I looked through all the threads online that I could but I have not found anything that helped me and I'm out of ideas.

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on a 5 year old Lenovo X240. I've tried connecting using the port VGA (on laptop) to HDMI (on monitor), but nothing. My laptop doesn't find anything when I try to "detect displays". I have an older W520 running that doesn't work either, but when I tried it with my wife's macbook air the monitor immediately recognizes the signal and connects.

I'm not sure what other info would be helpful for you to help me with this. But if you ask I find it and add it to this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try booting a Live CD of Ubuntu 16.04 or older. You can get 16.04 here:
https://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/

See if that activates your display in this older version.

If it does, try booting Live of 20.04, there is a "Try before you install" option on standard Ubuntu ISO image, but make sure you pick "saef graphics".

If that works, you'll have terrible resolution, but you'll be on a way to solution - that means that graphics driver (probably Intel) in newer Ubuntu versions is bugged and doesn't respond well to what your display sends back (EDID info).

I keep running into that thing with some displays, hard to say if it's Intel's or display manufacturer's fault.. but those same devices work fine with older kernels and/or Windows.

Comment: I will give this a try. Thank you.